# Formula to count how many different mobile numbers each user has in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on Excel 2010 and there are 3 different columns with the following headings:
-Name
-Mobile No.
-Count how many different mobile no.'s each user has

There may be more than one mobile number for each user and I am trying to count how many different mobile numbers each user has.

I have tried the following formulas but none of them seem to work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data)) 

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A10, A1:A10)>0,1))
```

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: In C3: Countif($A$1:$A$10,$A1) asuming your data is in rows 1 to 10, otherwise change accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your attempts I assume that the same number might repeat for the same user and you want to count the **distinct** numbers? If so, try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$9=A1)/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9,$B$1:$B$9,$B$1:$B$9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Column A contains the name, Column B contains the mobile number, and D1 contains the name of interest, try...

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$1:$A$10=D1,IF(LEN($B$1:$B$10)>0,MATCH($B$1:$B$10,$B$1:$B$10,0))),ROW($B$1:$B$10)-ROW($B$1)+1)>0,1))
```

...confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Hope this helps!